# How to get the id of auto generated select2

Tags: jquery-select2

What i want to do is to alert the selected value in select2 dropdown but the problems is i don't know the id of the dropdown because it is auto generated

```
$("#whatisthename").select2();

$('#whatisthename').on("change", function(e) { 
var val = $(this).val();
alert(val);
});
```

[image]

Comment: can you add the code here. So that its easy to reply a answer

Comment: @NipunTharuksha the code is on the picture

Comment: yes i saw that but it will be better if you could add the full code rather that attaching a image. If you wants i can submit a sample

Comment: @NipunTharuksha basically that's the whole code, its auto generated that can bee seen in inspect element only

Comment: ok then add the code that use for auto generating